# Styling within handle bars

Tags: javascript, node.js, ember.js, handlebars.js

I am new to ember and could use some help trying to style my progress bar I have created. This is what is creating the progress bar:

```
 {{ember-progress-bar style=myStyle shape="Circle" useDefaultStep=false progress=model.points options=(hash strokeWidth=5 duration=600)}}
```

and I would like to style it using this code in the controller:

```
export default Ember.Controller.extend({

    myStyle: "color: #3a3a3a"

});
```

but this does not work. Any suggestions on what I need to do differently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use attributeBinding for style attribute. In `ember-progress-bar` component inlclude the below statement,

```
attributeBindings:['style']
```